# How is J() function implemented in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I recently learned about the elegant R package `data.table`. I am very curious to know how the `J` function is implemented there. This function is bound to the function `[.data.table`, it doesn't exist in the global environment.

I downloaded the source code but I cannot find the definition for this `J` function anywhere there. I found `lockBind(".SD", ...)`, but not `J`. Any idea how this function is implemented?

Many thanks.

Comment: You might find http://adv-r.had.co.nz/dsl.html helpful for describing the general techniques by which this sort of thing is implemented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`J()` used to be exported before, but not since 1.8.8. Here's the note from `1.8.8`:

> o The `J()` alias is now removed *outside* `DT[...]`, but will still work inside `DT[...]`; i.e., `DT[J(...)]` is fine. As warned in v1.8.2 (see below in this file) and deprecated with `warning()` in v1.8.4. This resolves the conflict with function `J()` in package `XLConnect` (#1747) and `rJava` (#2045). Please use `data.table()` directly instead of `J()`, outside `DT[...]`.

Using R's *lazy evaluation*, `J(.)` is detected and simply replaced with `list(.)` using the (invisible) non-exported function `.massagei`.

That is, when you do:

```
require(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(1:5, each=2L), y=1:10, key="x")
DT[J(1L)]
```

`i` (= `J(1L)`) is checked for its type and this line gets executed:

```
i = eval(.massagei(isub), x, parent.frame())
```

where `isub = substitute(i)` and `.massagei` is simply:

```
.massagei = function(x) {
    if (is.call(x) && as.character(x[[1L]]) %chin% c("J","."))
        x[[1L]] = quote(list)
    x
}
```

Basically, `data.table:::.massagei(quote(J(1L)))` gets executed which returns `list(1L)`, which is then converted to `data.table`. And from there, it's clear that a `join` has to happen.