# About the new features J() of data.table 1.9.2

Tags: r, data.table

I'm happy to find `data.table` has its new release, and got one question about `J()`. From [`data.table` NEWS 1.9.2](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md#datatable-v192-on-cran-27-feb-2014):

> `x[J(2), a]`, where `a` is the key column sees `a` in `j`, #2693 and FAQ 2.8. Also, `x[J(2)]` automatically names the columns from `i` using the key columns of `x`. In cases where the key columns of `x` and `i` are identical, `i`'s columns can be referred to by using `i.name`; e.g., `x[J(2), i.a]`

There're several questions about `J()` in S.O, and also the introduction to `data.table` talks about the binary search of `J()`. But my understanding of `J()` is still not very clear.

All I know is that, if I want to select rows where "b" in column A and "d" in column B:

```
DT2 <- data.table(A = letters[1:5], B = letters[3:7], C = 1:5)
setkey(DT2, A, B)
DT2[J("b", "d")]
```

and if I want to select the rows where A = "a" or "c", I code like this

```
DT2[A == "a" | A == "c"]
```

much like the data.frame way. **(minor question: how to select using a more data.table way?)**

So to my understanding, '`J()` only uses in the above case. select two single value from 2 different columns.

Hope my understanding is wrong. There're few documents about `J()`. I read [How is J() function implemented in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001945/how-is-j-function-implemented-in-the-r-package-data-table). `J(.)` is detected and simply replaced with `list(.)`

It seems that every case `list(.)` can replace `J(.)`

And back to the question, what the purpose of this new feature? `x[J(2), a]`

It's really appreciated if you can give some detailed explanations!

Comment: These should be probably be separate questions.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your suggestions, now I put them in separate questions!

Comment: @Arun, sure, I updated the questions and put the expected result for `DT[, sum(A,na.rm=FALSE), by = B]`. Also, I put the questions in different post, and modified the title. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.()` and `J()` as the `function` wrapping the `i` argument of `data.table` are simply replaced by `list()` because `[.data.table` does some programming on the language of the `i` and `j` arguments to optimize how things are done internally. It can be thought of as a alias for `list`

The reason they are included is to allow save time and effort (3 key strokes!)

If I wanted to select key values `'a'` or `'c'` from the first column of a key I could do

```
DT[.(c('a','c'))]
# or
DT[J(c('a','c'))]
# or
DT[list(c('a','c'))]
```

If I wanted `A='a' or 'c'` and `B = 'd'` then I would could use

```
DT[.(c('a','c'),'d')]
```

If I wanted `A = 'a' or 'c' and B = 'd' or 'e'` then I would use `CJ` (or `expand.grid`) to create all combinations

```
DT[CJ(c('a','c'),c('d','e'))]
```

The help for `J`,`SJ` and `CJ` is quite well written! See also the vignette [Keys and fast binary search based subset](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html).