# R data.table join

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have a question concerning data.table join.

What does the **dot** does in the following join :

```
DT1[.(DT2$key),roll=TRUE][,V1]
```

Both data.tables are key by the column "key".

Comment: Same thing as `J` does. Type `?J` to find out more about it. And if both `data.table`'s are keyed, normal syntax is `DT1[DT2, ...]`.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001945/how-is-j-function-implemented-in-the-r-package-data-table/22002174#22002174) may help.