# subset data with key in R using `data.table` package

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have the following data table tb1

```
persid    date        rating
10000     1/1/2014    A
10000     1/2/2014    B
10001     1/1/2014    A
10001     1/2/2014    B
10002     1/1/2014    A
10002     1/2/2014    B
 .          .         .
 .          .         .
 .          .         .
```

I set `persid` as the key by using command:

```
setkey[tb1, persid]
```

But when I run the command:

```
tb1['10000']
```

it is giving me an error msg:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(prhistory, "10000") : typeof x.persid (integer) != typeof i.persid (character)
```

But if I remove the quotation, i.e. just `tb1[10000]`, then it is giving me the value of the 1000th row.

So how can I subset with a key that is an integer in this data table?

I am using package `data.table`.

Thanks

Comment: It's `swetkey(tb1,persid)` - parens, not brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these will work

```
setkey(tb1,persid)
tb1[J(10000)]
#    persid     date rating
# 1:  10000 1/1/2014      A
# 2:  10000 1/2/2014      B
tb1[persid==10000]
#    persid     date rating
# 1:  10000 1/1/2014      A
# 2:  10000 1/2/2014      B
```

Comment: Thanks, both worked! Just curious, what the `J` did to `10000`?

Comment: @PerriMa, it's a shortcut to convert to a `data.table` for `join`. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001945/how-is-j-function-implemented-in-the-r-package-data-table/22002174#22002174).